# Verificar se campo telefone é igual

Tags: jquery

Pessoa preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Eu preciso de uma validação que é a seguinte.

Em meu form eu tenho dois campos de telefone, TEL1 e TEL2.

A validação é a seguinte se TEL2 == TEL1 Da uma alerta falando que o numero já foi informado.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

JS:

```
$('[name="telc2"]').change(function () {
    ValidacaoTelefone();
});


function ValidacaoTelefone() {
    var telefone1 = ('[name="telc1"]').val();
    var telefone2 = ('[name="telc2"]').val();

    if (telefone2 === telefone1) {
        console.log("teste");
    }
}
```

Comment: informe seu código para ajudarmos, se tiver algo errado iremos orientar.

Comment: Qual sua dúvida? A pergunta parece uma encomenda de código... Não tem nenhum que sirva de base?

Comment: editei o topoico com o codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando seu exemplo...

```js
$('[name="telc2"]').blur(function () {
    ValidacaoTelefone();
});


function ValidacaoTelefone() {
    var telefone1 = $('[name="telc1"]').val();
    var telefone2 = $('[name="telc2"]').val();

    if (telefone2 != telefone1) {
        console.log("Diferente");
        return;
    }
    
    console.log("Igual");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="telc1" />
<input name="telc2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Primeiro,** isto esta errado:

```
var telefone1 = ('[name="telc1"]').val();
var telefone2 = ('[name="telc2"]').val();
```

Deveria ser:

```
var telefone1 = $('[name="telc1"]').val();
var telefone2 = $('[name="telc2"]').val();
```

Pode verificar usando o evento `onblur`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var telefone1 = $("[name=telc1]"),
      telefone2 = $("[name=telc2]");
  
  $("[name=tel1], [name=tel2]").on('blur', function() {
    var v1 = telefone1.val(),
        v2 = telefone2.val();

    if(v1 == v2) {
      alert('Numero ja informado!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" name="telc1" value="">
    <input type="text" name="telc2" value="">
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pega o valor de cada *input* e compara eles da seguinte forma:

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="tel1" id="tel1" />
    <input type="text" name="tel2" id="tel2" />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tel1, #tel2').blur(function() {
    var tel1 = ('#tel1').val();
    var tel2 = ('#tel2').val();

    if(tel1 == tel2) {
      alert('Numero ja informado!');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Teria como fazer de uma outra forma onde ele verifica assim que troca de campo? tipo digitei 1111 no tel1 ai eu digito 1111 no tel2, quando eu troco para outro campo ele verifica

Comment: Alterei minha resposta.